# database authentication with cas server module

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I am in process of implementing SSO for two web-applications (both jsp-servlet MVC based).
The user credentials in sqlite database "App1.db" within table LOGIN(USERNAME,PASSWORD).
CAS's official page mentions support for MySql and oracle ,but nowhere it mentions non-compatibility with "other" databases .So, is there a way to integrate this sqlite database with CAS server module for authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the CAS Server documentation is community driven. The authors of the page you referenced have worked with MySQL and Oracle. I personally have connected it up to Microsoft SQL Server without issue... because it uses JDBC.

CAS JDBC Authentication Handler uses Spring and JDBC. JDBC is generic by design. So if your sqlite database has a JDBC driver, then you should be good to go.